# преобразовать строку похожую на Json в массив

Tags: php, json

Имеется строка похожая на `json`:

```
{&quot;Result&quot;:{&quot;Result&quot;:&quot;OK&quot;,&quot;Message&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;Success&quot;:true,&quot;ServerDate&quot;:&quot;\/Date(1458043610512)\/&quot;,&quot;Timings&quot;:null},&quot;Message&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;Success&quot;:true,&quot;ServerDate&quot;:&quot;\/Date(1458043610512)\/&quot;,&quot;Timings&quot;:null}
```

Как из нее сделать массив? `json_decode()` возвращает `null`. сейчас ковыряю `preg_replace()`, но сомневаюсь что это удачное решение

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
json_decode( html_entity_decode( $data));
```